# Inline comments are not submitted using Conduit API

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I am trying to add inline comments via the Conduit API, and am using the command `arc call-conduit differential.createinline`. The request succeeds, however the comment is marked as unsubmitted.

[image]

The end goal is to be able to have my build job add these comments programatically, but this isn't useful if the comments are not ultimately submitted. Any advice on how to create inline comments & submit them?

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to submit the inline-comment using the `attach_inlines` on `differential.createcomment`

```
echo '{
 "revision_id":<revision_id>,
 "attach_inlines": true
}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri <conduit-uri> --conduit-token <conduit-token> differential.createcomment
```

but this functionality was removed in https://secure.phabricator.com/D21225

Comment: non-comment from [ignormis](/users/8134178/ignormies): You used to be able to submit the inline-comment using the `attach_inlines` on `differential.createcomment`, but this functionality was removed in https://secure.phabricator.com/D21225.